# Dynamically add new div in grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have little problem, because I would like dynamically add (create) new div (cell of grid) click on button. This is simple, but trouble starts when I want this divs add three in line and add next row below (again three columns) and always new div will be add as first. Summary I would like dynamically create grid with three columns and infinity rows, and new div will be always first.

Thank you for your time and help :)

[image]

Comment: So what have you tried so far? Many tutorials online and questions just like that have been answered on stackoverflow... If you haven't tried anything yet then I suggest you start with some research. If you have tried something then I suggest you include your attempt(s) in your question.

Comment: Show some code, how you are adding div in the container

Comment: Check these two sites: [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) and [`prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

Comment: of course I tried and I am still trying and I can do it in js but only in one direction horizontal or vertical but I can't handle with three elements horinzontal and next in new row below etc. But thank you for answer :)

Comment: So you want to dynamically show DOM elements on user events? Then take a look at AngularJs, that's one of its main purpses... this and the fact that you can dynamically add in a text javascript variable content, update them in your js and Angular will do the job on the Dom too. He can do many othe usefull things,  but really if you want to change the DOM dynamically use a framework builded for that, AngularJS and ReactJS are the most usefull and common ones, with great comunity (lik here) and many documentation.

Comment: Are you using jQuery? Because if you *are* please add that tag to the question, otherwise I'm unnecessarily penalising two answers for providing jQuery answers to a non-jQuery question.

Comment: Sorry, my fault, yes I am using jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is like this, using **[jQuery](https://jquery.com/)** and its  [**append()**](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method:

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  $('#container').append($('<div class="item">'));
});
```

```css
div.item{
  width: 30%;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Add div</button>
<div id='container'>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
</div>
```